# Insert Based on Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, data-warehouse

In our data warehouse (SQL Server 2005), we attempt to insert/update records in order of the primary key.  In other words, we pull from the source table and issue an ORDER BY *primary key in DW*.  This is a standard practice to keep the data reads/writes in logical order on the hard drive and improve performance.  (If this is not accurate, please let me know).

When issuing an ORDER BY on a very large source table, this really kills performance.  Is there another way to get the same result?  I am thinking some combination of index rebuilds and computing stats?

Hope that makes sense!  I'm not a DBA!  Thanks.

Comment: You pull from the source table to where?

Comment: I know plenty of reasons for wanting to process or insert records sorted by the primary key, but performing the actual sort in the source system put unnecessary load on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is "standard practice", but I worked in a warehouse where our typical table had close to a billion records.  We would always drop the indexes, insert the new data, and then rebuild the indexes.  Someone, at some point, determined this was the most efficient way for us to do it.  I'm sure someone here can chime in about page size and physical attributes (which is probably more than you need to know, since you say you're not a DBA), but the short answer is to do it that way.

If you decide to go that route, always remember to drop the non-clustered indexes first, and then drop the clustered.  When you rebuild them, rebuild them in reverse order (clustered first and then non-clustered).

Comment: If you build the non-clustered then the clustered, all of the non clustered get recreated based on the clustered. This would take more time.

Comment: You're right, Rick.  Brain fart.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a specific ordering, you **must** have an order by clause. No ifs, ands, or buts. A clustered index on the column you want to sort by would probably make the select run faster, but building that index may end up taking just as long as your original query.

I would look into alternative methods of re-ordering your target table (as suggested in Johnny Bones's reply).

Answer (score 0):

If that table does not have an index, then the pages aren't going to be stored with any particular order on the disk.  In the case of a large table without any index, a SELECT.....ORDER BY from said table will have a performance issue.

It sounds like you need an index on your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If the table you are pulling from has a clustered index on the PK (which it should), then bringing back records in the order of the PK should have zero performance impact.  Any performance issues you are having is probably due to the sheer number of records you are returning (not to the ORDER BY).

I don't think I understand what you're trying to do, exactly.  But bringing back the records in that order should not be a problem.